# How to remove empty lines within multiple lines that reside in one cell?

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I got results from Outlook into Excel using VBA. There are some cells that hold multiple lines in one cell, like this

```
line 1
line 2



another line


final line
```

I tried regular expression "^$" to remove the empty lines.

And worse, since all the lines are in once cell, I cannot use a formula to merge them.

What is in between the lines?  I used "^$" to match them and replace with "". That means there is nothing left but still the empty lines are there.  I also removed "chr(13)".

Comment: The symbol between the lines is chr(10). Your change crossed my answer, so I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to remove all line breaks?

```
YourResult = replace(replace(YourCellValue, chr(10), ""), chr(13), "")
```

Or do you just want to remove the empty lines?

[edit]
The answer above wasn't tested. I see now that the character separating the lines is chr(10), so you only need to replace that:

```
YourResult = replace(YourCellValue, chr(10), "")
```

Also, if you want to keep multiple lines, but remove the empty lines, you can replace two line breaks with one, and repeat that step until no changes are left:

```
Function FixLines(value As String)
  Do
    s = value
    value = Replace(value, Chr(10) & Chr(10), Chr(10))
  Loop Until value = s
  FixLines = value
End Function

YourResult = FixLines(YourCellValue)
```

Comment: this is the best answer to this issue along this line - among all the answers I googled. THANK YOU, GolezTol!